# Windows CE device powering off Randomly 

Tags: windows-ce

I have a touch screen device that is running on windows CE. after 30 second the screen goes off to save power and will come back on it you touch it.

The problem is that randomly when the screen goes off the device will not come back on simply by touching the screen. I have a done a bunch of tests and there is no noticeable pattern to when this happens.

It appears to be performing the same action as when you press the suspend button from the main menu.

I have done some research and found there are 4 power saving settings in the registry and I think I need to disable one to stop the device from "suspending". I never want the device to turn off except for the screen going off, it is always connected to power.

Does anyone know how I can do this or why it is randomly suspending ?

And the entire device is in Chinese So really precise instructions would be appreciated. My application runs on top of the CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're after precise instructions, but it's not that simple.  The device OEM defined and implemented the power management system for the device, Microsoft only provided the structure for it.  The OEM could have implemented power management in any way they sought fit,, and in fact they could have completely ignore the Microsoft-provided framework (wouldn't be the first time an OEM did that).  Really you need to get a hold of the OEM and ask them how to prevent the behavior you're seeing or to get something different.

Barring that, you could always play around with the registry entries, but again, there's no guarantee any of them will work.  You might look at adjusting [power state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889692.aspx) or the [activity timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889826.aspx) registry entries.

Playing with the power manager control panel applet might also help (it's probably labelled 电源管理)

Comment: Thanks but how do I get to the registry ?

Comment: The Remote Registry Editor (installed with Studio 2005/2008) is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts]
    "BattSuspend"=dword:0

Comment: Yes, but the "screen shuts off but comes on when touched" is not a suspend.  FOr some reason the device sometimes powers off the backlight and at other times completely suspends the device.  I suspect a flaky timeout algorithm.